# Como llamar un Store Procedure MySQL que solo recalcula unos datos, en Net Core 5 MVC

Tags: mysql, mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo un SP MySQL que solo recalcula los saldos de Almacen, el procedimiento solo devuelve una bandera donde indica que temino el proceso.

Como puedo llamar al procedimiento desde un boton que esta en una vista, ya que no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Este es el código donde tengo varias acciones

```
<!-- Encabezados del formulario -->
<div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Titulo del formulario -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3>Inventario de Almacenes</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- Botones de acciones -->
        <div class="col-md-4 text-end">
            @*<button href="#WinModal" id= "btnNewOc" type="button" asp-controller="DoctosAlmMaster" asp-action="ReceiveByOCSelect" class="btnNewOc btn btn-primary btn-md" data-bs-toggle="modal" title="Nuevo Elemento OC" ><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Nuevo</button>*@
            <!-- Menu Acciones -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Acciones </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a id="btnIndex" class="dropdown-item" href="/DoctosAlmMaster/Index"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-left"></i> Movimientos de Almacén</a></li>
                    <li class="p-3"><strong> Accesos rápidos</strong></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" style="margin-top: -10px;"></li>
                    <li><a id="btnIndex" class="dropdown-item" href="/HiloOcMaster/Index"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i> Órdenes de Compra</a></li>
                    <li><a id="btnIndex" class="dropdown-item" href="/AlmacenEntSalHilo/Index"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i> Seguimiento E/S de Hilo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Incluir el boton Refrescar -->
            <partial name="~/Views/Shared/Controls/_BtnReloadDatatable.cshtml"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>      <!-- Fin Encabezado Formulario-->
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En principio podrías hacer una consulta SQL que llame al procedimiento: CALL recalcula_saldo_almacen;

Comment: Muchas gracias por la idea, @Calabacin no se me había ocurrido eso, lo probaré y les cuento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el codigo final

Este es el controlador

```
public IActionResult RecalcularSaldos()
{
    StringBuilder sbSqlCmd = new($"CALL DoRecalcularSaldosAlmacen();");
    DataTable procedureResult = Singleton.Instance.Connection.Select(sbSqlCmd.ToString());
    /* Mostrar un mensaje de informativo */
    this.AddHtmlInformationMessage("Los Saldos fueron actualizados correctamente.", true, true);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Y este es parte de la vista donde llamo al controlador

```
<li><a id="btnIndex" class="dropdown-item" href="/AlmacenSaldos/RecalcularSaldos"><i class="fa-solid fa-calculator"></i> Recalcular Saldos</a></li>
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Veo que al final mi solución te sirvió. Me alegro.